# Passing arguments through parameter in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am passing an argument using implicit return.

Point out what's wrong please, Ruby does not provide any feedback error for the implicit return, it is just blank with no response.

```
def add(a, b)
  a + b
end

def subtract(a, b)
  a - b
end

add(20, 45) 

subtract(80, 10)
```

I know it works in terminals. Is that the only way to work this code? I know the puts way to make this work using code editor that forces an implicit return that is not nil.Trying to do the same with this method.

Comment: what's the question? The code is valid and methods are correct and working.

Comment: When I pass the code, nothing happens. thanks Andrey for the code thingy.

Comment: :) Just run the code in terminal and see output. If you run it as file, add `puts add(20, 45)` to actually output the result

Comment: Ya I already know it works in terminals.  Is that the only way to work this code? I know the puts way to make this work using code editor.

Comment: did you put it in <%= add(20, 45) %> to print it out?

Comment: I am following a book, the book asked me to type this in code editor but this method seems to work in terminal but no luck in code editor.

Comment: code editor does not run your code. Which is OK, nothing to worry about. Continue to read the book.

Comment: This method only works when directly entering into the terminal itself? Of course I know code editor does not run the code. It passes them to the terminal to run it, if you thought I did not knew. I have another chunk of code that need to be understood similar to this, which is why my question.

Comment: This issue is not specific to ruby by the way...

Comment: The question is clear and concrete. Maybe, it is too simple for somebody. But THAT is not forbidden.

Comment: Thanks Gangnus, I did my best. At least a positive reply from someone validates my question is legit.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a *read-evaluate-print-loop* (REPL) like `irb` then you'll see the output of your code as you type it in. If you're in a code editor you probably will not.

Here's how to get some output from that code:

```
def add(a, b)
  a + b
end

def subtract(a, b)
  a - b
end

p add(20, 45) 

p subtract(80, 10)
```

Putting `p` before any given thing will give you a quick `inspect` (debug) view into the object in question. Normally Ruby will just throw away any results in a void context like this, you're not asking it to preserve the results of these method calls anywhere, nor display it in any form, which is why there's no output.

I have my editor configured to run Ruby code with the push of a button, so maybe yours has an option to do that as well. Most do it in some form but it may require some configuration.

Comment: Thanks tadman, it works perfectly now I will do the configuration, thanks heaps. I am using sublime editor.

Comment: In Sublime it's CTRL+B or Command+B to run your code if you have all the Ruby bits plugged in and working properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, tadman.

Comment: Hi tadman I like the quote from your profile about Unconscious Competence and Mastery beautifully put:"You need to realize that when you practice from the state of the beginner all the way to the stage of immutable wisdom, then you must go back to the status of the beginner again."